# Annuity and Perpetuity

Tags: finance, actuarial-science

> A thirty-year annuity X has annual payments of $\$1,000$ at the beginning of each year for twelve years, then annual payments of $\$2,000$ at the beginning of each year for eighteen years. A perpetuity $Y$ has payments of $Q$ at the end of each year for twenty years, then payments of $3Q$ at the end of each year thereafter. The present values of $X$ and $Y$ are equal when calculated using an annual effective discount rate of $10\%$ . Find $Q$.

We have that the discount rate is $d=.1$. Therefore $i=\frac{.1}{.9}=.11$. Our present values are:

$$X=1000\ddot{a}_{\overline{12}|i}+2000\ddot{a}_{\overline{18}|i}(1+i)^{-12}$$$$Y=Qa_{\overline{20}|i}+3Qa_{\overline{\infty}|i}$$

My instructor then writes that if we set these equal to each other we get $12040.14=11.75Q$. I haven't the slightest on how he simplified $Y$ to $11.75Q$, I've tried all the formulas for present value of annuity and perpetuity but it's not correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression you wrote for the present value of the perpetuity is not correct, because the present value of the payments of $3Q$ should be discounted by the $20$ years of deferral that passes after the first $20$ annual payments of $Q$ are made.  That is to say, $$Y = Qa_{\overline{20}\rceil i} + 3Q v^{20} a_{\overline{\infty}\rceil i},$$ where $v = (1+i)^{-1} = 1 - d = 0.9$ is the present value discount factor.  Alternatively, because the interest rate is fixed across all payments, you may equivalently regard the cash flow $Y$ as comprising two level perpetuities-immediate, one that pays $Q$, and the other paying $2Q$ after $20$ years:  $$Y = Qa_{\overline{\infty}\rceil i} + 2Q v^{20} a_{\overline{\infty}\rceil i} = Q(1+2v^{20})a_{\overline{\infty}\rceil i} = \frac{1+2v^{20}}{i} Q,$$ which is a simpler expression to evaluate.  In both cases, the result is $11.1884Q$.

Comment: I've noticed that you are one of the few and proud ones who answer actuarial-related questions on MSE, and I was wondering if you could possibly help me with this problem: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2516962/actuarial-risk-problem-how-to-find-probability-of-an-event If so, I would be eternally grateful! Thank you.